# Angular 8 material design only after server restart

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, nrwl-nx

I got a problem while learning Angular 8 with material design.

I copy pasted a material design example from here https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview, it looks like this:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

When I start my Angular server with `npm start` the site is on localhost:4200 and I can watch it. And there it is in material design.

[image: material design]

now the fun stuff happens and I have no idea whats going on. After I save my file, even after just deleting one character and readding it, the hot reload function kicks in and reloads my site. Now I see this:

[image: not material design]

I have absolutely no idea what code I should show you, because I have no idea what's going on, but if you request any file, I can put the content of that file here.

Furthermore I can tell that I'm working in a monorepository and the angular project was created by nrwl.

I'm completely new to web dev so I have no idea what's going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to change enableIvy true to false. You will get it in you tsconfig.app.json file of your angular project. This works for me.

Comment: when I try to disable enableIvy I can't compile it with the error message: ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.6.4 was found instead.

Comment: ok cool. just make the enableIvy to true and try to apply the answer which i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line in your angular.json file of your angular project

```
"aot": true
```

This solved my problem.
Hope it will workout in your case as well.